# What is correct process to physically move an availability replica to another location

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Current situation is we have 3 SQL Servers with one availablity group and we plan on moving one of the secondary replicas out of HQ to another location.  There will be the span of a few hours between the transport of the server to the new location.  Would it be best to suspend the databass on the replica and then resume once its up again?

Comment: Please define "moving".  Will a completely different server become a secondary replica?  Or will the current secondary replica just be down and then come back up?

Comment: Sorry, we will be powering off that replica and moving it to a new datacenter.  Then powering it back up.